# face recognition library doesn't recognize faces that is detected by the library

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-detection

Thankful for [ageitgey](https://github.com/ageitgey), I can try [face recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) instantly. However, I got a problem.  Faces detected by the library are not recognized by the library.

What I have tried is:

1. detected faces in an image by `face_detection` and saved them:

```py
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

# Load the jpg file into a numpy array
image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")

# Find all the faces in the image using the default HOG-based model.
# This method is fairly accurate, but not as accurate as the CNN model and not GPU accelerated.
# See also: find_faces_in_picture_cnn.py
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

for face_location in face_locations:

    # Print the location of each face in this image
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
    print("A face is located at pixel location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

    # You can access the actual face itself like this:
    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.show()
```

2. execute `face_recognition` on the saved image:

```py
mport face_recognition

# Load the jpg files into numpy arrays
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama2.jpg")

# Get the face encodings for each face in each image file
# Since there could be more than one face in each image, it returns a list of encodings.
# But since I know each image only has one face, I only care about the first encoding in each image, so I grab index 0.
try:
    biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]
    obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]
    unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
except IndexError:
    print("I wasn't able to locate any faces in at least one of the images. Check the image files. Aborting...")
    quit()

known_faces = [
    biden_face_encoding,
    obama_face_encoding
]

# results is an array of True/False telling if the unknown face matched anyone in the known_faces array
results = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_faces, unknown_face_encoding)

print("Is the unknown face a picture of Biden? {}".format(results[0]))
print("Is the unknown face a picture of Obama? {}".format(results[1]))
print("Is the unknown face a new person that we've never seen before? {}".format(not True in results))
```

As a result, it returns no faces in the image...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if the images are really loaded here:

```
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama2.jpg")
```

and then that you really getting face encodings here:

```
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]   
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]
unknown_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
```

That's the only "bottlenecks" I can see in your code now.

Comment: Bohdan, thank you very much. Sorry for this late reply.

Comment: As I have tested, I figured out that this library and code works fine; however though it detects any faces well, it does not recognize well to Asian faces (I am Asian). I think I need to train the model. Currently I don't know how to do it though..